# Why randomly generated word is not retaining?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using following approach to generate a random word. "wordsToMakeRandomEmail" is a array of words. I am using storyboard with a UITableViewController.

There is also a search bar controller. First time Random email is generated well and shown in UITableViewController's table view. But when I select a cell, it is shown as nil. Any help will be great.

Thanks.

```
-(NSString*)getRandomWord
{
  NSUInteger randomIndex = arc4random() % [wordsToMakeRandomEmail count];
  NSString *string = (wordsToMakeRandomEmail)[randomIndex];
  return [string copy];
}

-(NSString*)getRandomEmail
{
  NSString *emailPrefix = [self GetRandomWord];
  NSString *email = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@google.com",emailPrefix];
  return [email copy];
}
```

And following methods are used for table cell construction:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Configure the cell...
    NSMutableArray  *emails;
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        emails = (searchResults)[indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        emails = (self.emailConversations)[indexPath.row];
    }

    EmailData *email = (emails)[0];

    if(email.IsReaden && tableView != self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        ReadEmailTableViewCell *readCell;
        readCell = (ReadEmailTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Read" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        readCell.Sender.text = email.Sender;
        readCell.Subject.text = email.Subject;
        readCell.Time.text = email.Time;
        NSString *inStr = [@([emails count]) stringValue];
        readCell.Count.text = inStr;
        return readCell;
    }
    else
    {
        UnReadEmailTableViewCell *unReadCell;
        unReadCell = (UnReadEmailTableViewCell *)[self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"UnRead" forIndexPath:indexPath];

        NSMutableAttributedString *s =
        [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:email.Sender];

        [s addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
                  value:[UIColor yellowColor]
                  range:NSMakeRange(0, s.length)];

        unReadCell.Sender.attributedText = s;
        unReadCell.Subject.text = email.Subject;
        unReadCell.Time.text = email.Time;

        NSString *inStr = [@([emails count]) stringValue];
        unReadCell.Count.text = inStr;

        unReadCell.Line1.text = email.Line1;
        unReadCell.Line2.text = email.Line2;
        return unReadCell;
    }

    return nil;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
    {
        return 115;
    }
    NSMutableArray *emails = (self.emailConversations)[indexPath.row];
    EmailData  *email = (emails)[0];
    if(email.IsReaden)
    {
        return 61;
    }
    return 115;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SettingsSegue"])
    {
        return;
    }

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = nil;
    EmailConversationTableViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;

    NSMutableArray *singleConversation;

    if (self.searchDisplayController.active)
    {
        indexPath = [self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        singleConversation = (searchResults)[indexPath.row];
    }
    else
    {
        indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        singleConversation = (self.emailConversations)[indexPath.row];
    }

    destViewController.emails = singleConversation;
}
```

Comment: you should show how you are populating your table view cell and also any code you have that gets called when a cell gets selected.  Also, best practice (or the common thing) is to start all Objective-C methods with lower case letters... so instead of "`GetRandomEmail`" do "`getRandomEmail`".  "`GetRandomWord`" should be "`getRandomWord`", etc.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann the objective-c common practice for getters is also not to prefix with the word 'get', :)

Comment: That's true @Jeff, but Najmul didn't say that these are `@properties`.  And I'm just trying to gently guide him to a solution.  He'll get to even better best practices as he goes along.

Comment: Thanks Michael and Jeff, have added methods for constructing cells and a method when cell get selected.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thanks everyone, After giving a brute force try, I have been able to solve the problem.

`EmailData` is a class created by me. It has some `NSString` properties. They were declared as `weak`. Imho, it was the cause for memory leakage. I have just changed it to `strong` and the problem is solved.

Old code:

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString *Sender;
```

updated code:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Sender;
```

Comment: `weak` does not cause a memory leak. It causes just the opposite, a dangling pointer. This was a very silly thing to do; you should stop and learn how memory management works.